# Trouble with _RCTReconnectingWebSocket with ExpoKit

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I'm experimenting an issue since some days ago, and I don't know what I made to have my project under a bad configuration. I hope explain it in a good way:

If I configure my scheme with build configuration set to Release, the build is ok. But when I changed the build configuration to Debug, the build is failed with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTReconnectingWebSocket", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTPackagerConnection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My project is a react native ejected with ExpoKit:

```
"expo": "^19.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-19.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Plus, the project has CocoaPods as a dependency manager (so I open the project with the xcworkspace file).

Any ideas what do I have wrong?

Comment: Have you tried clearing DerivedData just in case?

Comment: Yeah! It works! Thank you very much @ide